# Decimal Pad in modal controller and close bar button item: how to pass value in MainViewController?

Tags: objective-c

I've a Decimal Pad in modal view controller that is shown automagically using:

```
    [self.TextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

I've an action in this modal that takes value from TextField:

```
- (IBAction)Text:(UITextField
                   *)sender {
self.SendText =  self.TextField.text;
NSLog(@"1 Triggered: %@", self.SendText);
}
```

I need to pass that value SendText in FirstViewController.
I've added a bar button item and connect to segue unwind in the FirstViewController.
In the FirstViewController:

```
- (IBAction)close:(UIStoryboardSegue *) sender { 
 if ([sender.identifier isEqualToString: @"Segue"]) {
   self.ViewModal = sender.sourceViewController ;
   self.LabelTextPassed.text = self.ViewModal.SendText;
   NSLog(@"2 Triggered: %@", self.ViewModal.SendText); 
 }
}
```

When execute that code why i received a 
2 Triggered null and 
1 Triggered with the exact value ? 
And in that inverted order ?
The value is triggered after and is not passed to FirstViewController ..

Comment: How and when is your Text:sender IBAction called?

Comment: Is it not automagically called when user types on Decimal Pad ?

Comment: Anyone has some suggestions ?